# jQuery UI - when dropped out of droppable return to original position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I use JQ.UI
I want to drag some img

if it's dropped out of a droppable area, I want it to return to its original position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [jQuery UI page for Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-revert):

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ revert: true });

//getter
var revert = $( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "revert" );

//setter
$( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "revert", true );
```

You can use `true`, `false`, `valid` or `invalid`.

In your case, you want `$( ".selector" ).draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });` so that any drops on invalid locations (not `droppable`s) cause a revert.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`revert`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#revert) option with a value of `invalid` to send the draggable back to where it came from if it's dropped anywhere other than on a valid droppable:

```
$("#someID").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
});
```